# designing Client Server Application in C#

Tags: c#, client-server, remoting

### designing Client Server Application in C#

I'm developing an application for copying and creating files between local network shares in 1 GB connection. This application will run on a local machine with that connection.

Now I have to introduce a Client-Server connection in a way that the User can perform the same steps from his Home PC. For that reason I have to setup a Server on the local machine which has 1GB connection to the network shares and access that server application from Home to perform the same actions as the User is on his local workspace.

Once again I want to clarify that the application now is running well on a local PC with 1 GB connection. I want to reach as much as possible to that via with the Client-Server. And once again, I'm not copying files from the Client to the Server or anything like that. It is only interaction between the local shares. So I want to be able to perform a copy function from local/share1/folder1 to local/share1/folder2 from the Home PC.

I'm new to Client-Server applications. And I have no idea how to set up that. Any recommendations/suggestions are welcome. My current application is developed in C# Visual Studio, so I believe that I should better use .NET Remoting or some other already supported by Visual Studio. All I could find on the internet is how to set-up a client server application for chat, I see nothing similar to my case.

Any design decisions or code will be really helpful at this moment.
There is no need to attach snippets of my code (I guess), because the application is already running locally and I don't have to change it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is too broad, and reading this its not clear at all what you actually want to do, or why you need an additional server to access resources that are already on a network.

Comment: The problem is that if you make a VPN connection from Home PC to the shares where the data is, the connection will be ~50 Mbit, not 1Gbit as it is inside the organization. That means a copying of a 3GB file will be done for 20 minutes instead of 1 minute if I'm executing that command from a local machine. That is why I want to make a server application running on that share, to handle this faster.